# Open notification settings page android oreo

Tags: java, android

I try to open the notification settings page using intent with `Settings.ACTION_APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS` and this should be with `intent.putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_PACKAGENAME)`. But this is opening notification setting only for one app. I want to open notification settings page for all apps! How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS`, you should get global notification settings.